# Is there any documentation for udev builtins?

Tags: udev, documentation, reference

The man page for udev mentions in several places that certain rules options can be used to invoke 'builtin' commands, which are apparently built in to the udev program itself. However, I haven't been able to find any reference documentation that clearly explains what udev builtins are available; what they do and how they are used.

I have searched the web without much success. Does anyone know if there is a reference anywhere that provides details about these builtin commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this information is missing on manpages and even knowing how to read them(see below) you will find trouble on trying to find that info.

However, the beauty of the opensource relies on having the power to read the sources. If you take a look at the [`udev-builtin.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin.c) source file inside `systemd`/`udev` repository and have basic [C language knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), you will find the following snippet of code: A structure that maps all existing builtin types.

```
static const struct udev_builtin *builtins[_UDEV_BUILTIN_MAX] = {
#if HAVE_BLKID
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_BLKID] = &udev_builtin_blkid,
#endif
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_BTRFS] = &udev_builtin_btrfs,
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_HWDB] = &udev_builtin_hwdb,
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_INPUT_ID] = &udev_builtin_input_id,
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_KEYBOARD] = &udev_builtin_keyboard,
#if HAVE_KMOD
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_KMOD] = &udev_builtin_kmod,
#endif
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_NET_ID] = &udev_builtin_net_id,
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_NET_LINK] = &udev_builtin_net_setup_link,
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_PATH_ID] = &udev_builtin_path_id,
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_USB_ID] = &udev_builtin_usb_id,
#if HAVE_ACL
        [UDEV_BUILTIN_UACCESS] = &udev_builtin_uaccess,
#endif
};
```

This `struct` holds all built-in types, and they map source files depending on what type it is. Example:

- [`udev-builtin-kmod.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-kmod.c) - A Kernel Module loader.
- [`udev-builtin-keyboard.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-keyboard.c) - A keyboard handler.
- [`udev-builtin-usb_id.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-usb_id.c) - A USB handler that will set the usb type and initialize the device.

**Related:**

- [How do I use man pages to learn how to use commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193815/34720)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it seems a bit bizarre that this information is not in the man pages, but can only be found by reading the sources.

Comment: Maybe it's not relevant to `systemd` team document this, as all those actions are pretty much  "automatic" (probe keyboard, handle usb, handle network link...) but yeah, i agree with you that even a simple explanation what those are would be great to avoid the loss of time of crawling through sources online...

Answer (score 13):

If you just run `udevadm test-builtin --help` it'll list the builtin commands along with a short description for each of them:

```
udevadm test-builtin --help
```

```
udevadm test-builtin [OPTIONS] COMMAND DEVPATH

Test a built-in command.

  -h --help     Print this message
  -V --version  Print version of the program

Commands:
  blkid           Filesystem and partition probing
  btrfs           btrfs volume management
  hwdb            Hardware database
  input_id        Input device properties
  keyboard        Keyboard scan code to key mapping
  kmod            Kernel module loader
  net_id          Network device properties
  net_setup_link  Configure network link
  path_id         Compose persistent device path
  usb_id          USB device properties
  uaccess         Manage device node user ACL
```

Unfortunately, as you've noticed, builtins usage is only explained briefly in the manual.
A practical example can be found in the file `50-udev-default.rules` available on your system (under `/lib/udev/rules.d/`) which contains stuff like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=usb"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{ID_INPUT}=="", IMPORT{builtin}="input_id"
ENV{MODALIAS}!="", IMPORT{builtin}="hwdb --subsystem=$env{SUBSYSTEM}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this and it is helpful. However, I am trying to diagnose a hardware initialization issue during boot, and I think it would really help if I could understand more details of what these functions are actually *doing*.

Comment: `udevadm test-builtin` by itself didn't do it for me. I had to add `--help` to get a list. Edited the answer to add the switch!

Comment: awsome.amazing/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if you don't find anything better, maybe try to explore which builtins are available directly in the source: look for files starting by "udev-builtin"

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/master/src/udev